# non-static variable favPic cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm stuck on one problem with my code below. I keep getting a compiler error in the main method when im trying to call the `setFavoritePicture`method. It says non-static variable favPic cannot be referenced from a static context. I'm relatively new to java so any help with this would be appreciated! Many thanks!

```
   public class House
{
  String owner;
  Picture pRef;
  Picture [] picArray;
  Picture favPic;

  public void setFavoritePicture (Picture pRef)
   {

    Picture favPic  = new Picture (FileChooser.pickAFile ());
    pRef = favPic ;


  }



  public static void main (String [] args)
   {
     House PhDsHouse = new House ("Mad PH.D.");
     PhDsHouse.setFavoritePicture (favPic);


   }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`favPic` is a **non-static** instance member of the `House` class and you are trying to reference it from within your **static** `main` method. You need to create an instance of `Picture` and pass that in instead:

```
Picture pic = new Picture(FileChooser.pickAFile ());
PhDsHouse.setFavouritePicture(pic);
```

However, it seems there are slightly deeper issues with this code, as your `setFavoritePicture` method doesn't actually set `favPic` according to the passed parameter, it sets it according to `FileChooser.pickAFile` and then assigns that value back to the passed parameter (which achieves nothing).

Maybe you wanted to do something like this instead:

```
public void setFavoritePicture (Picture pRef)
{
    favPic = pRef;
}
```

Update: Regarding your comment:

> I need to, within the 'setFavoritePicture' method, pick a picture,
>   using 'FileChooser.pickAFile ()'. Thats the whole point of this
>   method.

In that case, why do you need a parameter at all? Perhaps something like this?

```
public class House
{
    String owner;
    Picture [] picArray;
    Picture favPic;

    public void setFavoritePicture ()
    {
        Picture pic  = new Picture (FileChooser.pickAFile ());
        this.favPic = pic;
    }

    ... /* Rest of your class here */

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        House PhDsHouse = new House ("Mad PH.D.");
        PhDsHouse.setFavoritePicture();
    }
}
```

In the above code, you instantiate your `House` and then call its `setFavoritePicture` method. If all of the logic behind creating a new picture is handled by that method, including the call to `FileChooser.pickAFile`, then you don't need to pass anything to it.

Having said that, it seems to me that the responsibility of `setFavoritePicture` should be to set the object's favourite picture and that handling file selection and user input should be done elsewhere (such as in my earlier example in which `pRef` is instantiated outside of the method and passed in).

Comment: Hes doing that inside of setFavouritePicture.  I dont think he understands OOP.  He needs to just get rid of the var and use this.

Comment: And then note that the `setFavouritePicture` method doesn't actually do anything at the moment... setting the value of a parameter doesn't change the state of the object.

Comment: I need to, within the `setFavoritePicture` method, pick a picture, using `FileChooser.pickAFile ()`. Thats the whole point of this method.

Comment: @AntP thank you, I know there's a much easier way to doing this but this is part of what my assignment entails unfortunately. I appreciate your help!